# How can I make 2 divs with a slash between

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want make a menu like the image but I don't know how to cut the two divs and make it clickable.

I have tried with svg and borders on divs but I can't get the divs nor svg together because the "outline" still a rectangle!

the image example its on this link:
http://postimg.org/image/ffp6g83fd/537cb837/

```
I only can make this :
********|   *****
******* |  ******
******  | *******
*****   |********

and I want :

******** *****
******* ******
****** *******
***** ********
```

and make them clickable

this was my result based on [Hugo Marabutt Nogueira](https://stackoverflow.com/users/875313/hugo-marabutt-nogueira) answer

http://jsfiddle.net/L7PL4/

Comment: Try http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp You can then define your custom shape as a shape area.

Comment: Check this out: http://codenip.com/?page=view&id=258

Comment: You can use :before and :after to add background-image to your element (svg or image). And as others said you can create your custom shape in css, a good set of example https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: many thanks it exactely what i want but i still can click on the white space between the boxes see this: http://jsfiddle.net/UyAwh/53/

Comment: If you want the area to be clickable you can have a look at the skew css property. It can allow you to make that shape clickable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS3 Transitions to achieve that shape and then bind a js click to them.

Like this :

http://cdpn.io/stHdg

```
.skew{
  background-color: #333;
  width:150px;
  height:75px;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  margin-left:100px;
  margin-top:50px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.a:before{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    background: #333;
    top:0;
    left:-25px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 50px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-20deg);
    transform: skew(-20deg);
}
.b:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    background: #333;
    top:0;
    right:-25px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 50px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-20deg);
    transform: skew(-20deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it without too much extra cruft. This uses borders and some css transforms to make the angles.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vSn87/)**

[image: Screenshot]

**CSS**

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;   
    height: 50px;
}
.left,
.right {
    float: left;
}

.left span,
.right span {
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 50px; // equal to height of element
}

.left {
    width: 25%; // change as needed
    border-bottom: 50px solid blue;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.left span {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg); // opposite of skew
}

.right {
    width: 25%;
    border-bottom: 50px solid green;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) rotateX(180deg);
}

.right span {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg) rotateX(-180deg);
}
```

Just make sure to unskew the text by using the opposite transforms on them. You'll also have to use all the appropriate vendor prefixing for transforms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative margin to make the element overlap. Example:

```
margin-right: -5px;
```

Comment: yes i can, but i wanna make it clickable so i will not work that well